# Case study section in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to have a 'case-studies' section within my 'About us' section of the site. I already have a news section which is pulling in the 'news' posts. My site structure currently looks like this:

- Homepage (page) About Us (page)

  - History (page)
  - Meet the team (page)
  - Case studies (page displaying case study posts as title and excerpt)
- Services (page)
- News (latest news posts)
- Contact (page)

I've set up the case-studies as a new category and pulled the posts onto the case-studies page template using a custom loop. This is working however when previewing a full case study post it displays it under the news section (probably because this is the default page, permalinks problem?).

How can i get it to display the full post but stay within the About us section? I know its jumping to news page because my anchor link within the menu shows up highlighted as active page.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom post type. You can add those with ['register_post_type()'](http://codex.wordpress.org/register_post_type). You especially need to look at the `rewrite` argument. Because herer you can customize the base url of the post type. Something like this:

```
//other args
 'rewrite' = array (
    'slug' => 'URLBASE' // puth the url base here
),
//other args
```

This should get you started. If you need more help ask.

Comment: What would the 'slug' be for the example i provided above? I would probably need the permalink to be about-us/case-studies/case-study-1 ?

Comment: I'm not sure if it can be `about-us/case-studies/` but if you use `case-studies` as slug that will be the base. I can't help you with that double nesting.